# Unable to hide marker from GMap v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I can have a bunch of locations with different categories to show on the map. Eventually I'd like to apply a filter on them. Probably the scenario is very familiar as I found many of them on the web while I was trying to solve my issue. I put the markers on my map and I can find no way to hide them. Here is how I try it:

```
function addLocations($content, id, map){
var $mapdiv = $content.find('div.map_div');
catValues = [map.catPrimary, map.catWhite, map.catGreen, map.catYellow, map.catRed, map.catBrown, map.catPurple, map.catGray, map.catOrange];
db.locations.all(function(obj){
    $.each(obj, function(index, location){
        if(location.value.nodeID == id){
            var latitude = location.value.latitude;
            var longitude = location.value.longitude;
            var description = location.value.description;
            var category = location.value.category;
            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            if(category == "0"){
                homeLocation = position;
                $mapdiv.gmap('get','map').setOptions({'center':position});
            }       
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: position, 
                icon: "assets/img/marker_" + category + ".png", 
                category: category,
                shadow: iconShadow,
            });
            marker.setMap( $mapdiv.gmap('get','map') );
            $mapdiv.gmap('addMarker', marker).click(function() {
                $mapdiv.gmap('openInfoWindow', { 'content': description + "<br/> (" + catValues[category] + ")"}, this);
            });
        }       
    });
    markers = $mapdiv.gmap('get', 'markers');
    for(var i = 0; i<markers.length; i++){
        if(markers[i].category != "0"){
            //"not primary, hiding  
            markers[i].setVisibile(false);
        }
    }
});
```

All the markers are shown and the ones that are supposed to be hidden are not. I also tried adding the markers to an array before I add them to the map and work with them, but no success. When I include the markers[i].setVisible(false) around a try and catch it says "Object #  has no method 'setVisible'. Surprisingly if I test markers[i].getVisible() I get the value true. 
I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the correct code is `markers[i].setMap(null);`

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#RemovingOverlays

From the article:

> Removing Overlays
>
> To remove an overlay from a map, call the overlay's setMap() method, passing null. Note        that calling this method does not delete the overlay; it simply removes the overlay from the map. If instead you wish to delete the overlay, you should remove it from the map, and then set the overlay itself to null.
>
> If you wish to manage a set of overlays, you should create an array to hold the overlays. Using this array, you can then call setMap() on each overlay in the array when you need to remove them. (Note that unlike in V2, no clearOverlays() method exists; you are responsible for keeping track of your overlays and removing them from the map when not needed.) You can delete the overlays by removing them from the map and then setting the array's length to 0, which removes all references to the overlays.

Comment: Acutally both setVisible and setMap are working if I don't put them str8 after  I add the markers to the map. If I create a button and then click it everything is fine. I'll accept your answer though.

Comment: Interestingly enough, you spelled `setVisible` as `setVisibile` in the code you posted, that may be part of your problem as well.